# How to delete the metadata from a nonexisting Domain Controler object in Active Directory Sites and Services

Tags: active-directory

**Short story:**

After SBS migration we have a mixed AD enviorment with one Win2003SBS (still in function) and two Win2008R2 doman controlers and one nonexistent DC in AD Sites and services that dates back several years before. Sometimes when we join another server/pc to the domain the join fails with error:

> The following error occurred attempting to join the domain
>   "domain.local": Cannot complete this function.

Googling the problem I've found that in order to fix the problem I need to wipe the metadata from active directory for the nonexistent DC.

According to [**this**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216498) Microsoft KB article that can be done with AD Sites and Services snap in in Win2008 or by using `ntdsutil` in Win2003.
**Because there is a mixed environment in question what is the right way to do erase the metadata? Should I use the AD Sites and Services in Win2008 or `ntdsutil` in Win2003?**

**Long story:**

Recently I've been performing a SBS2003 -> 2008 domain upgrade.
So far so good, however while joining aditional computers to the domain Win2008 and Win2012 I've noticed that sometimes the join to the domain fails with error:

> The following error occurred attempting to join the domain
>   "domain.local": Cannot complete this function.

.. and after the 2nd or the 3rd try the join is successful.

Goggling the problem I found [**this**](http://blog.mpecsinc.ca/2013/08/domain-join-error-cannot-complete-this.html) article that says that this can happen if there is a faulty or nonexistend DC in AD Sites and Services.

I don't know how I haven't noticed before but in fact there IS a nonexistent DC in AD Sites and Services and this is dating back 6-7 years ago when apparently the company had a major system failure with the SBS causing them to restore the domain from the backup (i wasn't working there at the time :) ). I can only assume that when restoring the domain they named the newly installed Win2003SBS server **PLUTON** instead of its original name **PLUTO** thus making the duplicate DC in AD Sites and Services.

Now [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216498) MS KB article describes the steps which are required in order to wipe the metadata and remove the faulty DC.

According to the article that can be performed directly from AD Sites and Services snap in Win2008 environment or i have to use `ntdsutil` in Win2003.

From the image below PLUTON is the Win2003SBS server and PHOENIX and VOYAGER are the two Win2008R2 domain controlers.

**Because there is a mixed environment in question what is the right way to do this? Should I use the AD Sites and Services in Win2008 or `ntdsutil` in Win2003?**

[image]

Comment: I don't know if there is a `right` way. If both ways work then they're both `right`. What I suspect you're really asking is `will either method make things worse?` and the answer is no, as long as you only cleanup the now long gone DC. If it were me I would use the AD Sites and Services method first and then verify it with the ntdsutil method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article does not really distinguish between 2003 and 2008, but it lists 2008 as supported for this procedure. So I'd just go ahead and do everything that's stated in "Procedure 1". This includes using ntdsutil as well as AD Sites + Services, so you actually need both.